# How to autodeploy whenever changes happen in code while using netbeans IDE and wildfly 19.1 application server

Tags: wildfly

I am using Jsf ,primefaces as front end and java files. Whenever i make changes i will run Maven copy the war file and paste into deployments folder manually. I want to autocompile whenver i make changes and deploy automatically

Answer (score 0):

If your budget permits, you can use the proprietary [JRebel](https://www.jrebel.com/products/jrebel) product. You don't have to redeploy after every change.

Also, in your case, instead of manually copying the war file to the application server, you can use [wildfly-maven-plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/)

```
mvn wildfly:deploy
```

or

```
mvn wildfly:redeploy
```

Comment: I cannot use jrebel. I am using Netbeans,JSF,primefaces,maven. I tried using maven-plugin. It didnt help.